# What do Futures and Agents in Akka offer over Clojure's counterparts?

Tags: scala, clojure, akka, future

Having watched the presentation [Composable Futures with Akka 2.0](http://youtu.be/VCattsfHR4o), I am curious to know what additional features the Akka implementation of Futures and Agents bring over Clojure's ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Agents in Akka are inspired by agents in Clojure." This is the first line in Agent documentation on Akka and hopefully it clears the agents part of question. As far as futures are concerned, they are both same conceptually (i.e invoking an operation on a separate thread). The underlying implementation are based on `java.util.concurrent`, so both using same underlying infrastructure.

**Scala part:**
The important part how the **composable** word come into play (both for agents and futures). If you go to akka docs you will find that you can use higher-order functions like `map`, `filter` etc. on Akka futures, i.e. a `map` operation on a future returns another future (and similarly for `filter`). This allows you to easily compose/chain together futures and wait on the final future for the final value. Now, all this is possible because the `map`, `filter`, `for` comprehension etc. are all based on Scala (monadic) API which basically allows any new type to provide specific implementations of these functions.

**Clojure part:**
Now on clojure side of things, you know that `map`, `filter` etc are just normal functions that work on  collections, i.e they work on something that can be traversed and hence are different concept from the Monadic API of scala. So in Clojure you will use different ways to compose futures after all Clojure (or Lisp in general) allow composability in many many ways